# Boolean.getBoolean("true") returns false

Tags: java

I'm trying to make function that reads ini file. Why  `Boolean.getBoolean("true")` returns `false`? How to use this conversation in correct way in java 1.4? Does it depends on system settings?

Comment: I think you're trying to get a boolean named "true"

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`Boolean.getBoolean()`'s argument expects the name of a system property. What you're looking for is `Boolean.valueOf("true")`

Answer (score 10):

The method [getBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String%29) takes a System Property name as an argument, not the String value of the boolean. What you need is probably [Boolean.parseBoolean()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: That's the way to go. :)

Answer (score 3):

Boolean.getBoolean("true") has this javaDoc:

Returns true if and only if the system property named by the argument exists and is equal to the string "true". (Beginning with version 1.0.2 of the JavaTM platform, the test of this string is case insensitive.) A system property is accessible through getProperty, a method defined by the System class.
If there is no property with the specified name, or if the specified name is empty or null, then false is returned.

You are looking for Boolean.valueOf("true")

Answer (score 2):

From [Boolean.getBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String%29)

> Returns true if and only if the system property named by the argument exists and is equal to the string "true".
>  
>   (Beginning with version 1.0.2 of the JavaTM platform, the test of this string is case insensitive.) 
> A system property is accessible through getProperty, a method defined by the System class.
>   If there is no property with the specified name, or if the specified name is empty or null, then false is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Boolean.parseBoolean("true")`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply